# Git revert merge to specific parent

Tags: git

I have a git repo and am having trouble reverting a merge. The current hash is 0ce2ca0b35f59af267241cf4d40d16a3e13ba6f3. and it has two parents:

```
df1acf5f54426d30f12c6b4558c3dd922297aae3
e19b912404ffd3c153ccac3072dbf22396896d2a
```

doing the following will revert to df1acf5f54426d30f12c6b4558c3dd922297aae3

```
git revert -m 1 0ce2ca0b35f59af267241cf4d40d16a3e13ba6f3
```

how do I revert to e19b912404ffd3c153ccac3072dbf22396896d2a?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
git revert -m 2 0ce2ca0b35f59af267241cf4d40d16a3e13ba6f3
```

Parents are numbered starting with 1; you want the second one.

Comment: `git show 0ce2ca0b35f59af267241cf4d40d16a3e13ba6f3`   

will tell which are the parents: `Merge: df1acf e19b91`

Comment: @lukmdo that should be `git show --format=full [hashish]`. The default setting of git show doesn't show merge parents.