# Reverting merge

Tags: git, merge, reverting

How do I revert a merge ?

I see referring to the parent id. How do we get the parent ID such as those mentioned in [Git revert merge to specific parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240230/git-revert-merge-to-specific-parent) ?

How do we get the number ?

```
git revert -m 1 0ce2ca0b35f59af267241cf4d40d16a3e13ba6f3
```

Comment: you want to revert particular commit??

Comment: @mrutyunjay  yes, I would like to revert to a particular commit

Answer (score 0):

You can do a

```
git show --format="%P" <SHA>
```

If your HEAD is the result of a merge:

```
git show --format="%P" HEAD
```

You can also display directly the SHA1 of each parent:

```
git rev-parse <SHA>^1
git rev-parse <SHA>^2
```

See also this old thread about "[merge revert](http://schacon.github.io/git/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt)".

Answer (score 0):

git revert {head#} -m {number of commits backwards you wish to revert}

After -m you just put a number like 2 or 1, for me I can't specify the exact commit number. Then a gui will come up and show what commit you're targeting to revert to is.

Head# is the actual {git number} 0ce2ca0 you wish to revert from.